# Why is it "si fui quien" and not "si yo fuera quien"?

Tags: gramática

Here is part of the lyrics of "Vas a Querer Volver" by Maite Perron.

> ***Si fui*** quien te quería
> Fui quien daba todo por ti
> Fui quien cada día
> Solo quiso hacerte feliz
> Quien te confiaba el alma ciegamente
> Fui quien te amaba incondicionalmente
> Quien te entregó su corazón de frente
> Y tú lo **olvidarías**

I thought that there are only certain ways you make **if statements** in Spanish

1. si + present + present / future / imperative
2. si + imperfect subjunctive + conditional
3. si + pluperfect subjunctive + conditional perfect

However ***"si fui"*** is si + preterite  and ***Y tú lo olvidarías** the conditional part

Additionally, if this is in fact an if statement, wouldn't it be something like
Si fui** quien te quería, <s>y</s> tú lo olvidarías? Why is there "y"?

Comment: can someone help me edit the lyrics to be line by line please.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't sí? (meaning yes)

Comment: @WalterMitty those were my initial thoughts but searching the lyrics revealed that its "si"

Answer (score 1):

The lyrics of this song are a reproach to something that has already happened:

> Si fui yo quien ... y tu lo olvidaste (and you forgot it)

> Si fui yo quien ... y tu lo olvidarías (and you would forget it)

The potential is set to facilitate the rhyme: *...quería, ...día, ...olvidarías*

If we change *"si fui yo quien"* by *"si yo fuera quien"* instead of a reproach it is a possibility, something that has not happened, a hypothesis.

> Si fuera yo quien ... tu lo olvidarías

Answer (score 1):

**ANTES DE RESPONDER**

En primer lugar, para que tu pregunta cobre sentido debemos dejar algo en claro:

> ...there are only certain ways you make **if statements** in Spanish.

Esto es completeamente **falso**. Sólo es un invento de los libros que se les dan a los extranjeros para que mecanicen y aprendan de memoria ciertas estructuras típicas. Más aún, [ni siquiera en el inglés se cumple](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330898/conditionals-1st-conditional).

Ahora bien, ¿cómo identificar un condicional? tiene que haber un **antecedente** y un **consecuente**, pudiendo aparecer éstos en cualquier orden. Típicamente las palabras mágicas son: *si* para introducir el antecedente y *entonces* para introducir el consecuente. En general, el *entonces* suele omitirse, y esto es obligatorio cuando se comienza mencionando el consecuente. En algunos casos se pueden usar otras palabras claves diferentes a *si* y con connotaciones distintas, por ejemplo: *mientras*, *si y sólo si* o *siempre y cuando*.

Por lo tanto, las estructuras condicionales a enumerar tienden a infinito. Es en parte uno de los lugares en donde se juega la libertad en el uso del lenguaje.

**INTENTO DE RESPUESTA**

Comencemos por citar todo el fragmento de la canción que es relevante:

> [Pre-Coro]
> Pero algún día vas a querer volver,
> al verme bien,
> besando amor en otros labios.
> Y el corazón te va a doler y vas a ver
> que estabas tan equivocado.[,]
>
> [Coro]
> **Si [si]** fui quien te quería,
> fui quien daba todo por ti,
> fui quien cada día
> sólo quiso hacerte feliz,
> quien te confiaba el alma ciegamente,
> fui quien te amaba incondicionalmente,
> quien te entrego su corazón de frente,
> **y** tú lo olvidarías.
>
> [Post-Coro]
> **Pero** vas a ver, y vas a ver.
> Vas a querer volver.
> Y vas a ver, tú vas a ver.
> Vas a querer volver.

Aún sin ganas suficientes de escribir *mi* propio manual que refute a los que existen, en base a lo que mencioné anteriormente consideremos cuatro estructuras muy generales con *si* (una es incorrecta):

> Si A entonces B
> Si A, B
> B, si A
> *Entonces B, si A

**¿Cuál es la que está presente en la canción?** Una posibilidad consistiría en el siguiente razonamiento: El *si* está delimitado por *y* y *pero*. Las construcciones ‘*si A pero B’ y ‘*si A y B’ carecen de sentido porque *pero* e *y* son conjunciones, por lo que éstas no pueden introducir un consecuente. Así, la estructura presente en la canción sería la tercera:

> B, si A

Donde:

> B: ‘el corazón te va a doler y vas a ver que estabas tan equivocado’

> A: ‘fui quien te quería, fui quien daba todo por ti, fui quien cada día sólo quiso hacerte feliz, quien te confiaba el alma ciegamente, fui quien te amaba incondicionalmente, quien te entrego su corazón de frente, y tú lo olvidarías’.

En este caso tendríamos *fórmulas compuestas* de varias *fórmulas simples*, las cuales están en una enumeración todas separadas por coma y con una *y* para la última fórmula. Siendo incluso más exquisito, la estructura sería: ‘[B1 y B2], si [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6 y A7]’, siempre y cuando no haya contado mal.

Me hubiese encantado que ésta fuera la respuesta correcta. Condicionales de este estilo son posibles de encontrar. Y aunque incluso se le puede dar algún sentido a que ‘le duela el corazón porque ella lo quería, etc.’, es muy improbable que la autora haya escrito pensando todo esto. Espero que algo te haya servido, consideralo una clase *express* sobre condicionales.

**RESPUESTA FINAL**

Retomemos la última pregunta. La respuesta que considero correcta es: ninguna estructura de las que presenté está en uso. En realidad, en este caso **no hay ningún condicional**. La acepción 5 para *si* del DLE nos da la clave:

> a principio de frase, da énfasis o energía a las expresiones de duda o aseveración.

**Por lo tanto: En este caso, el *si* no introduce un antecedente de condicional, sólo está dando más énfasis a lo que sucedió.**

Por supuesto que usar el verbo subjuntivo (‘fuera’) no tiene sentido porque las aseveraciones efectivamente se dieron. Dato de color: cuando en los condicionales la condición se cumple es posible reemplazar el conector *si* por *puesto que*, *debido que*, *dado que*, *porque*, etc.